# How to update plugins in a distributed wordpress scenario?

Tags: plugins, nginx, server-load

I have wordpress running with nginx behind a load balancer. Everything is running well. However, given that I have multiple sets of files, what's the best way to update them all? Ansible? Looking for some advice. Thank you

Edit: Amazon's EBS (similar system) requires that the files be updated on a local machine, and transferred to ebs with GIT. Not a standard use of version control, but seems to be very effective for this purpose. The one thing I wonder about this - should the plugins be installed (db updates) or simply have the file laid over the worker nodes and then installed? I wonder if wordpress plugins store settings locally, or all use the db?

Comment: Define "best"? :) Fast? Convenient? Atomic? Keeping servers in perfect sync?

Comment: All of the above! Check out my edit